# I need a StackExchange Data Explorer query to identify spam accounts

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, spam-detection

Something like this (in pseudocode):

```
 if answers > 3 and answers-with-url / total-answers > .5 
 then you-are-a-spammer
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You could just use the `User.IsASpammer` field, but they don't include it in the data dumps :(

Comment: _</couldn't-resist>_

Comment: Matching a URL inside a text field in SQL will be difficult if possible.

Comment: @SLaks a primitive test for `http://` and `www.` will create some false positives but my gut feeling is they won't be too many

Comment: @Pekka: It will catch anyone talking about protocols, hostnames, DNS, URI schemes, and other fields.

Comment: Sounds like a modwork question.

Comment: @SLaks yeah, but my feeling is that if they do that in more than 50% of their answers, it is likely that they are spammers. Worth a try at any rate, even if I'm wrong

Comment: I think it's okay to have false positives, since a moderator will be looking at each one before a decision is made.

Comment: Things you can do to narrow the search-- user accounts will be created within the last few months, they will have no questions, they will have no comments, they will have less than twenty answers, their rep will be below 5.

Comment: @SLaks: A real "plz-give-me-the-codez" question would be: "Hi, I'm new to Android development.  Can u plz help me write the next Angry Birds?"

Comment: @Robert AAAANDROID!  Slowly I turned... step... by step... inch... by inch...

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working version of SLaks query :

```
-- Spam Accounts
-- Users with > 50% answers with links
SELECT
   *
FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM Users u WHERE Id > 0 AND Id < 100000) u
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*) * 2 
     FROM Posts p 
     WHERE u.Id = p.OwnerUserId AND 
           (CHARINDEX('http://', LOWER(p.Body)) > 0 OR 
            CHARINDEX('www.', LOWER(p.Body)) > 0)) >
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts p WHERE u.Id = p.OwnerUserId)
```

Note : This query takes long to execute so if you want to see any result, you need to select only part of the user.

Funny fact : If we consider this metric Jeff Atwood is considered a spammer.

---

A couple modifications I've made to this query which have worked pretty good...

- restrict to last 10k users who have joined the system
- too lazy/don't care to provide their name
- less than or equal to 11 rep
- no questions

I already snagged three spammers off this one.

```
SELECT u.id as [User Link]
FROM (SELECT top 10000 * FROM Users u order by u.Id DESC) u
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*) * 2 
     FROM Posts p 
     WHERE u.Id = p.OwnerUserId AND 
           (CHARINDEX('http://', LOWER(p.Body)) > 0 OR 
            CHARINDEX('www.', LOWER(p.Body)) > 0)) >
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Posts p WHERE u.Id = p.OwnerUserId) AND 
    u.DisplayName is null AND u.Reputation <= 11 AND
    (select COUNT(*) FROM Posts p where u.Id = p.OwnerUserId AND PostTypeId = 1) = 0
```

Comment: Ran the query before reading the last line and I destroyed his account.  Good job, there.

Comment: Added a couple of refinements, hope you don't mind; adding a new answer would have been kinda ripoff-ey

Comment: I suggest an additional modification to ensure that URLs local to SE are not counted. I'm not sure if it's possible to do easily, but you might get fewer false-positives that way.

Comment: @Jason there's a TON of safe urls that show up in this.  php.org, apache.org, etc etc...

Comment: @Will good point, might not be worth the trouble then.